# Using a disk backed queue

Tags: java, architecture, wildfly

Under certain conditions, one of our servers running legacy code in a Wildfly application server, is suffering thread starvation and needs to be restarted.

After an arduous investigation, I stumbled upon this silly code:

```
private void addToQueue (Item e) {

     if (!_queue.offer(e, 200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) { 
              ThreadService.getInstance().schedule("retry process", () -> {
                addToQueue(e);
                return null;
              }, 5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
    }
```

ThreadService is the Wildfly implementation of the Java SE Executor Service, that provides a limited number of threads (16).

Sometimes, during reconnections between services, we receive in short time a huge amount of items to be processed (~100k), and as you can see it spams the ThreadService with scheduled tasks.

An obvious solution would be to increase the queue, which has currently a capacity of 20k. However I am afraid this would end up in other problems. Obviously this thread creation spamming needs to be eliminated.

Since processing these items is a non critical task I was thinking on using a disk backed queue, so it can be done in a separated process at slow pace.

Searching a bit, I have seen this project: [Tape by Square](https://github.com/square/tape)

I would like to know your opinion about this solution, which kind of reminds me a bit to the pipes in Linux I used years ago. What do you think?

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using? If you're using Jakarta EE 8, have you tried the `ManagedExecutorService` which is managed by the container?

Comment: Looking over the projection you mentioned, I see that it's no longer maintained, so if you encounter any issues, you'll most probably have to fix them by yourself. What problems would show up if you increase the queue? Maybe an OOM because too many tasks have to be kept into memory, right?

Comment: @James, we are using exactly that.

Comment: @Cosmin, yes, I think for the moment I will increase the size of the queue, and simply try to insert all items without this wait in the offer